# Migrating from Tire to Elasticsearch-rails, how do I translate search block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, elasticsearch, tire

I am finally upgrading Tire to Elasticsearch-rails and am having trouble finding examples on how to translate one to the other.  Here's my old query:

```
s = Item.tire.search do
  query { string query.query } if query.query.to_s.length > 0
  page = search_page
  min_score  Setting.get("elastic search min score", "0.1").to_f
  search_size = query_search_size
  from (page -1) * search_size
  size search_size
  filter :term, real_sale: true
  filter :terms, :retailer_id => [query.retailer_id] if query.retailer_id
  filter :not, {:exists => {:field => :location_ids} } if location_ids.nil?
  filter :terms, :location_ids => location_ids if not location_ids.nil?
end
```

I don't see any documentation about how to do a block in Elasticsearch-rails, can someone point me in the right direction?  I've tried the obvious, replacing tire with elasticsearch and just search, but neither of those worked.

Thanks for any help,
kevin